# Can PostgreSQL Select after LEFT JOIN??? jsonb array?

Tags: postgresql

my postgresql version is 14.9
there is a_table:

| Name (Txt) | Detail (JSONB) |
| --- | --- |
| apple | [{ "code": "156", "color": "red" }, { "code": "156", "color": "blue" }, { "code": "235", "color": "blue" }] |
| orange | [{ "code": "156", "color": "yellow" }, { "code": "234", "color": "ornage" }] |
| lemon | [{ "code": "156", "color": "green" }, { "code": "156", "color": "blue" }, { "code": "156", "color": "black" }] |

I want this select sql output :

```
| Name (Txt)   | Detail (JSONB)                             |
| --------     | ------------------------------------------ |
| apple        | [{ "code": "156", "color": "red"}]         |
| apple        | [{ "code": "156", "color": "blue"}]        |
| orange       | [{ "code": "156", "color": "yellow" }]     |
| lemon        | [{ "code": "156", "color": "green" }]      |
| lemon        | [{ "code": "156", "color": "blue" }]       |
```

there is a_table:

| Name (Txt) | Detail (JSONB) |
| --- | --- |
| apple | [{ "code": "156", "color": "red" }, { "code": "156", "color": "blue" }, { "code": "235", "color": "blue" }] |
| orange | [{ "code": "156", "color": "yellow" }, { "code": "234", "color": "ornage" }] |
| lemon | [{ "code": "156", "color": "green" }, { "code": "156", "color": "blue" }, { "code": "156", "color": "black" }] |

I did test my sql code

```
""" select a.*,j from 
  public.a_table  a 
  cross JOIN lateral json_array_elements ( Detail::json ) as j
  WHERE j->>'code' = '156' order by a.Name desc """
```

result output :

| Name (Txt) | Detail (JSONB) |
| --- | --- |
| apple | [{ "code": "156", "color": "red" }, { "code": "156", "color": "blue" }] |
| apple | [{ "code": "156", "color": "red" }, { "code": "156", "color": "blue" }] |
| orange | [{ "code": "156", "color": "yellow" }] |
| lemon | [{ "code": "156", "color": "green" }, { "code": "156", "color": "blue" }, { "code": "156", "color": "black" }] |
| lemon | [{ "code": "156", "color": "green" }, { "code": "156", "color": "blue" }, { "code": "156", "color": "black" }] |
| lemon | [{ "code": "156", "color": "green" }, { "code": "156", "color": "blue" }, { "code": "156", "color": "black" }] |

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! In future, could you go [here](https://dbfiddle.uk) and construct a fiddle with the necessary `CREATE TABLE...` and `INSERT INTO...` statements - help us to help you! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will unnest the JSONB array and create a new JSONB object for each element containing the 'code' and 'color' fields:

```
SELECT
    "Name (Txt)"
  ,  jsonb_build_object('code', elem->>'code', 'color', elem->>'color')  AS "Detail (JSONB)"
FROM your_table,
     jsonb_array_elements("Detail (JSONB)") AS elem
WHERE elem->>'code' = '156';
```

| Name (Txt) | Detail (JSONB) |
| --- | --- |
| apple | {"code": "156", "color": "red"} |
| apple | {"code": "156", "color": "blue"} |
| orange | {"code": "156", "color": "yellow"} |
| lemon | {"code": "156", "color": "green"} |
| lemon | {"code": "156", "color": "blue"} |
| lemon | {"code": "156", "color": "black"} |

And, if you really need the brackets, concatenate them to the output:

```
SELECT
    "Name (Txt)"
  ,  '[' || "Detail (JSONB)"::text || ']'  AS "Detail (JSONB)"
FROM (
    SELECT
        "Name (Txt)"
      ,  jsonb_build_object('code', elem->>'code', 'color', elem->>'color')  AS "Detail (JSONB)"
    FROM your_table,
         jsonb_array_elements("Detail (JSONB)") AS elem
    WHERE elem->>'code' = '156'
    ) D
;
```

| Name (Txt) | Detail (JSONB) |
| --- | --- |
| apple | [{"code": "156", "color": "red"}] |
| apple | [{"code": "156", "color": "blue"}] |
| orange | [{"code": "156", "color": "yellow"}] |
| lemon | [{"code": "156", "color": "green"}] |
| lemon | [{"code": "156", "color": "blue"}] |
| lemon | [{"code": "156", "color": "black"}] |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hosB-VkA)